# Is instagram users/self/media/recent API deprecating?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

As a result of their Cambridge Analytica damage-limitation, Facebook have just announced a bunch of immediate changes to the Facebook APIs and the Instagram APIs.

I have a running project that makes heavy use of Instagram API **users/self/media/recent**

Reference Link: https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

According to this reference url, api **/users/{user-id}/media/recent** is depriciating soon, So in my case I am also making use of /media/recent api but on {self} and not using {user-id}.

So my question to you guys is - Are both of these API's same and both are going to be discontinued? (I strongly hope thats not the case :) )

If yes, then what is the possible alternate to fetch instagram recent user feed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody knows, but it seems Facebook/Instagram is doing panic changes to all endpoints that give you information about any user that has not given you direct consent. So you can get information to the user who has approved your app, but I believe all endpoints that give public info will be removed or limited.

Comment: So for my instance, I have direct concent of the end user, so will I still be able to get the user's feed?

Comment: Any Solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API endpoint like all old Instagram API will be deprecated. You can read the note here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

They are migrating to Facebook Graph API. I believe that all developers using old Instagram API will have to migrate at some point to FB Graph API. Currently there is no support for fetching media from regular users. FB Graph API is running only for Instagram Business Accounts.

Most probably they will add support for regular Instagram accounts in the future. They are adding new endpoints so sooner or later equivalent to /users/self/media will be available in Graph API.

Answer (score 3):

> They are the same (when using 'self' obviously), it will be deprecated
> sometime in the future but not just now, I just tested them and it
> works
>
> [https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=%5BYOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN%5D)

This endpoint is now retired, so this response is no longer valid. Should I delete or just let this edit ?

Comment: Yes, my app is working fine as of now, just need to be sure my app dont break due to depriciation of this api endpoint. Do you see any alterate way of achieving same?

Comment: @Ka. would you mind removing this answer? This endpoint is not deprecated and it could be confusing for future users.

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can get this data 
check this link 
https://www.instagram.com/selenagomez/?__a=1
just change your username and you will be able to fetch data